# NavigationView Compact and Overlay

Tags: c#, uwp

I`m exploring the navigationview control for uwp projects. I noticed that when I resize the window to a smaller size the menu changes to compact mode and, if the the window is small enough it overlays over the right page window rather than pushing it to the side.

I want to change the navigationview control to have this behavior by default without having to resize the window to a smaller size. The goal is to have the page window with the most space available possible.

I tried some properties but none worked, any pointers how to change this default behavior(Overlay and always in compact mode)?

Answer (score 1):

you should use the latest [NavigationView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview) by **winui** library, and in this control you have a property **PaneDisplayMode**, explore values of this property and you can know what exactly you want. In your scenario you want the left pane to completely disappear and overlay then you can try **LeftMinimal** but if you want it in compact mode which shows only Icons then you can use **LeftCompact**

Answer (score 1):

You can try to confugure the [CompactModeThresholdWidth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview.compactmodethresholdwidth#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_NavigationView_CompactModeThresholdWidth) and [ExpandedModeThresholdWidth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview.expandedmodethresholdwidth#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_NavigationView_ExpandedModeThresholdWidth) properties of [NavigationView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview). These properties will get or set the minimum window width at which the NavigationView enters **Compact** or **Expanded** display mode.

```
 <NavigationView CompactModeThresholdWidth="280" ExpandedModeThresholdWidth="2800"/>
```

You can set the width value base on your requirement. For example, if you want the `NavigationView` alway in **Compact** Mode, you can use above code with any `CompactModeThresholdWidth` property value smaller than the minimum default UWP app window width and the `ExpandedModeThresholdWidth` property value larger than the maximum window width.